# Sencha with phonegap Native open external link

Tags: extjs, cordova, external-url

I have deployed a native app android + ios with sencha touch + phonegap.
If we click a link inside the app it opens inside the app and we cannot go out.

Does someone now how it is posible to let links open into the phone browser?

Answer (score 1):

```
window.open("yoururl", '_blank');
```

Answer (score 0):

The phonegap version I used was 2.9.0 if I am not mistaken.

I had the same problem and solved it as follows:

Embed the JQuery javascript file in your project. In my case it was:

`<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>`

Then I wrote the following function, which I called in the onDeviceReady function:

```
    function enableHttpLinks() {
        $('.externalLink').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            url = $(this).attr("href");
            window.open(url, '_system');
        });             
    }
```

In order for this function to work, you have a assign the class `externalLink` to all the links you want to open in the device browser, as shown below:

`<a href="..." class="externalLink">your link title</a>`

good luck...

Answer (score 0):

Just add this function inside "launch" function, in the app.js like this:

```
launch: function() {
    // Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element
    //Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();

    // Initialize the main view
    Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('yourApp.view.Main'));

    // Voila :
    Ext.Viewport.element.dom.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        if (e.target.tagName !== 'A') {
            return;
        };

        var url = e.target.getAttribute('href');
        var containsHttp = new RegExp('http\\b'); 

        //if href value begins with 'http'
        if(containsHttp.test(url)) { 
            e.preventDefault();
            window.open(url, "_system"); // For iOS
            navigator.app.loadUrl(url, {openExternal: true}); //For Android
        }
        else {
            return;
        }
    }, false);
}, //...
```

Then you can build for android and iOS at the same time.